How to use the value of a cell to find another cell?
I’m trying to create my own data sheets for reading at school but when I put the reading ages in, I need it to select the zpd level and the reading targets automatically base on what I input.
Eg if I put 16.06 in reading ages (cell c2) , I want it to say 5-13 (in cell d2) automatically. Then I want it to say 26 in termly target (cell e2)
But if I put 15.04 in (cell c2) then (cell d2) would say 4.8-11.2 and (cell e2) would say 23.4 under target.
Column j,k and l convert reading ages to points and targets. So only want to type in column c then have column d and e auto filled.


Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please [edit] your question and insert a table of sample data together with another table that shows your manually entered desired results.

Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Do you already know about formulas, functions and cell and range references in Google Sheets?

Use vlookup() and sort(). Clear cells D2:E and put this formula in cell D2:
=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(
  C2:C19, sort(J3:K), { 2, 3 }, true 
)))

The values in cell C2:C and J3:J must be numbers like 15.04.
To place this formula in row 1 so that it is not affected by sorting the sheet and the like, clear columns C1:E, put "Years" in cell C1, and modify the formula like this:
=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(
  C1:C, sort(J3:K), { 2, 3 }, true 
)))

See vlookup() and sort().

Formula is placed in the headings row  in cell D1 so it is separated from the data and isn't affected by sorts etc.
={"ZPD", "Termly Targets"; 
  BYROW(OFFSET(C:C, 1, 0, XMATCH(TRUE, INDEX(C:C<>""),,-1)-1), 
    LAMBDA(r, IF(r<>"", LET(
      val,IFERROR(r*1, SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(
        REGEXEXTRACT(r, "(\d*)" & {"y";"m"}) / {1;100}))),
      IFNA(FILTER(K:L, 1*J:J=val))),)))}


Clear column D and E and put formula in D1.
Column C values can be numbers or text strings like 12.06 or text strings where the years are followed by "y*" and the months are followed by "m*". For example, 12y6m, 12y 6months, 12yrs , 12y6momomomonths, etc.
Column J values can be numbers or numbers as strings. For example, 12, "12", 12.04, "12.04", etc.


"isn't affected by sorts" — the C2:C100 reference in the formula will get changed when the sheet is sorted, and will no longer get the expected result. Start the reference from row 1 and leave it open-ended to avoid that. One way to do that would be with byrow(filter(C1:C, row(C1:C) > 1), ....

Good catch!  Ty! I've updated to use an open column reference and to remove empty rows after the last populated row using OFFSET(C:C,1,0,XMATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C:C<>""),,-1)-1). This avoids issues if there are empty rows within the data.
